# BiometricPrompt Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-biometric-prompt

I would like to use biometric authentication on my application.

To do this in my view I declare a `val context = LocalContext.current` as its value and then I cast it to FragmentActivity.
But it crashes all the time with the following error: com.example.MainActivity cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity, and I can't find another method to find a FragmentActivty from a Composable View for BiometricPrompt.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `com.example.MainActivity` is not subclass of `FragmentActivity`

It should be like `class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() { ... }`

Comment: Hi!

Thanks! Now there is no crash, except that in my callback I have an error, the error code is 12 and the message, I have Biometric material unavailable.

The test device has only one code so no biometrics, and I use setAllowedAuthenticators(DEVICE_CREDENTIAL) to force the phone's pin code request except that before api 29 it doesn't work
 
Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure I get it, you're saying that your test device doesn't have a biometric sensor and you also can't use pin because it's older than 29? looks like you can't test it on your device, but you can try testing on the emulator

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, my phone does not have biometrics, I tested it on the emulator and it works! My current concern is that I'd like to ask the user for their password in case biometrics is not available, but I don't think this is possible on Android. I'm new to Android development btw.

Comment: @Paul I'm afraid I don't have much experience in this field, you'd better start a new question.